# Allowing users and anonymous to view website, but securing part of it

Tags: php, silex

I got problem: I want to allow both users and anonymous view  website, and allow only users to take certain actions ( which i got covered). The thing is that certain paths ( /account etc) should be accessible only to logged users.
I tried really hard to configure my secure.php but, either anonymous can access /account or I can't access logged user anywhere except /account/...

tried both :

```
$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
'secured' => array(
    'pattern' => '/account',
    'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/account/login_check'),
    'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/account/logout', 'invalidate_session' => true),
    'users' => $app->share(function () use ($app) {
        return new UserProvider($app['db']);
    }),
),
'unsecured' => array(
  'pattern'=> '/',
    'anonymous' => true,
)
);
```

and

```
$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
'secured' => array(
    'pattern' => '/account',
    'anonymous'=> true,
    'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/account/login_check'),
    'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/account/logout', 'invalidate_session' => true),
    'users' => $app->share(function () use ($app) {
        return new UserProvider($app['db']);
    }),
),

);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do that in the authorization step, so you have to configure the [`security.access_rules` key](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/security.html#defining-access-rules).

You can do this with a single firewall by enabling anonymous and authenticated users in it and then, with access rules, restrict access to /accounts URIs to only allow authenticated users:

```
<?php

$app['security.firewalls'] = array(
'secured' => array(
    'pattern' => '^.*$',
    'anonymous' => true,
    'form' => array('login_path' => '/login', 'check_path' => '/account/login_check'),
    'logout' => array('logout_path' => '/account/logout', 'invalidate_session' => true),
    'users' => $app->share(function () use ($app) {
        return new UserProvider($app['db']);
    }),
);
// By using authorization the access to the /account/* is protected to
// users with the ROLE_USER (you can be more creative here if you want)
// and with the second rule the whole site is allowed to non authenticated
// users (remember the /login path must not be protected!)
$app['security.access_rules'] = array(
  // this could be also array('^/account', 'ROLE_USER')
  array('^/account', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'),
  array('^.*$', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')
);
```

See [Symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/access_control.html) for more information on authorization. Also if you want to know more about access control without roles [check this out](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#checking-to-see-if-a-user-is-logged-in-is-authenticated-fully)

Comment: Yeah, figured it out yesterday the same way. Even tho, thanks for your time and effort :)

Answer (score -1):

The Easiest way is to set a session in the page headers.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["logged_in"])){
  header("Location: http://www.example.com/");
}
```

This is quite primitive - Have you thought about using a MVC framework? Would save you a of a lot of time.

Why not create a Controller?

Comment: Well, it is primitive, I could also check role before showing content of website, but I know there is more "professional" and complex way using silex security... Thanks for the answer tho ;)